# Is there a way to change permission on any directory from drwxrwsrwx to drwxrwxrwx?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a directory whose structure is as below. Want to change the permission from drwxrwsrwx to drwxrwxrwx

```
drwxr-xr-x  20 root       root        4096 Apr  5 08:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x  20 root       root        4096 Apr  5 08:55 ../
drwxrwsrwx   3 superadmin superadmin  4096 Apr  5 09:29 app/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is `set-group-ID` bit, to remove it use:

```
chmod g-s app
```

See `man chmod` for more information on how `chmod` handles `set-user-ID` and `set-group-ID` for directories.